# Combine two views in a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I don't know what is the best practice to do that but if I need a stored procedure to fetch data from multiple views.

I have two views first one of them passing parameter `CreationDate` to it and second one execute the first one with additional statements.

What I want to do is to select data fro these two views from C# code; I am using ASP.NET Webforms, VS 2010 to get the result from second view after changing the `CreationDate` from the first view.

This is the select from the first view called `VwInprogressSub1`

```
select 
    CurrentAgentFK, 
    Count(*) as TotalLeads,
    Sum(CASE WHEN LeadTicket.leadticketstatusfk=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AssignedCount,
    Sum(CASE WHEN LeadTicket.leadticketstatusfk=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS InProgressCount,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DaysToGetInProgress=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RespondedSameDay,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DaysToGetInProgress=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RespondedSecondDay,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DaysToGetInProgress=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RespondedThirdDay,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DaysToGetInProgress>2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RespondedMorethanThreeDay
 from 
     leadticket
 where 
     isfullleadticket = 1 and isold = 0
     and leadticket.CreationDateLG >= 20200201
     and leadticket.CreationDateLG <= 20200229
 group by 
     CurrentAgentFK
```

This is the select from the second view called `VwInprogress` :

```
SELECT
    dbo.VW_User.BranchFranchiseeName AS Branch,
    dbo.VW_User.UserName,
    dbo.VwInprogressSub1.TotalLeads,
    dbo.VwInprogressSub1.AssignedCount,
    dbo.VwInprogressSub1.InProgressCount,
    dbo.VwInprogressSub1.RespondedSameDay,
    dbo.VwInprogressSub1.RespondedSecondDay,
    dbo.VwInprogressSub1.RespondedThirdDay,
    dbo.VwInprogressSub1.RespondedMorethanThreeDay,
    (((((dbo.VwInprogressSub1.RespondedSameDay) * 5) +
       ((dbo.VwInprogressSub1.RespondedSecondDay) * 3) +
       ((dbo.VwInprogressSub1.RespondedThirdDay) * 2))) -
      ((dbo.VwInprogressSub1.RespondedMorethanThreeDay) * 2)) AS Score,
    dbo.Vw_AgentsInAllTeams.TeamManagerUsername
FROM
    dbo.VwInprogressSub1
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.VW_User ON dbo.VW_User.UserIdLG = dbo.VwInprogressSub1.CurrentAgentFK
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.Vw_AgentsInAllTeams ON dbo.VW_User.UserIdLG = dbo.Vw_AgentsInAllTeams.UserPK
WHERE
    dbo.VW_User.IsApproved = 1
```

Comment: Ahem. ... what exactly do you want to do with these two `SELECT` statements? Are they related somehow, do you want to join the resulting data on a common column (or set of columns)? Or how else do you want to make use of these two result sets in your stored procedure? You need to explain more in order for us to be able to help you ....

Comment: @marc_s somehow  I want to display the result of the `second view` after changing the `leadticket.CreationDateLG` of the the `first view`

Comment: @marc_s i updated the question with name for each view to make every thing clear

Comment: CurrentAgentFK is the unique key relation  to join these two result sets

Comment: @marc_s My answer not clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved my issue for what i want to do with two sets of views i need enhancement this stored procedure because it takes more time for execute .

Any Advice

```html
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ScoreReport   
    @CreationDateFrom datetime,   
    @vCreationDateTo datetime   
AS   

    SET NOCOUNT ON;     
 SELECT
dbo.VW_User.BranchFranchiseeName AS Branch,
dbo.VW_User.UserName,
VwInprogressSub1.TotalLeads,

VwInprogressSub1.AssignedCount,
VwInprogressSub1.InProgressCount,


VwInprogressSub1.RespondedSameDay,
VwInprogressSub1.RespondedSecondDay,
VwInprogressSub1.RespondedThirdDay,
VwInprogressSub1.RespondedMorethanThreeDay,
 
(((((VwInprogressSub1.RespondedSameDay)*5)+
((VwInprogressSub1.RespondedSecondDay)*3)+
((VwInprogressSub1.RespondedThirdDay)*2)))-
((VwInprogressSub1.RespondedMorethanThreeDay)*2))


AS Score,
dbo.Vw_AgentsInAllTeams.TeamManagerUsername

FROM
(select CurrentAgentFK,Count(*) as TotalLeads,
Sum(CASE WHEN LeadTicket.leadticketstatusfk=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AssignedCount,
Sum(CASE WHEN LeadTicket.leadticketstatusfk=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS InProgressCount,
Sum(CASE WHEN DaysToGetInProgress=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RespondedSameDay,
Sum(CASE WHEN DaysToGetInProgress=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RespondedSecondDay,
Sum(CASE WHEN DaysToGetInProgress=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RespondedThirdDay,
Sum(CASE WHEN DaysToGetInProgress>2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RespondedMorethanThreeDay




 from leadticket

where isfullleadticket=1 and isold=0
and leadticket.CreationDateLG >= @CreationDateFrom
and leadticket.CreationDateLG <= @vCreationDateTo

group by CurrentAgentFK) as VwInprogressSub1
INNER JOIN dbo.VW_User ON dbo.VW_User.UserIdLG = VwInprogressSub1.CurrentAgentFK
left JOIN dbo.Vw_AgentsInAllTeams ON dbo.VW_User.UserIdLG = dbo.Vw_AgentsInAllTeams.UserPK
WHERE
dbo.VW_User.IsApproved = 1
 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap each view in a separate stored procedure, fetch the results and do further logic in C# code.
Here's how you create stored procedure and open connection, create command and execute stored procedure.
You didn't specify ORM framework so I assume you would like to use stuff from System.Data.Sqlclient.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedure]
  @CreationDate INT
AS
BEGIN
   -- ... view select
END
```

```cs
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure", connection) { 
                           CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) {
   connection.Open();
   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CreationDate", creationDate));
   var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

   while (reader.Read())
   {
      // Logic depends on how are you going to store view results. DataTable? DTO?
   }
}
```

--EDIT
Further to conversation SqlDataAdapter approach:

```cs
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure", connection) { 
                           CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) {
   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CreationDate", creationDate));

   using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command)) {
      var dataTable = new DataTable();
      dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
   }

}
```

Comment: What is logic if i store view result in DataTable

Comment: and the second StoredProcedure for the second View how will be write it because it depend on the first one

Comment: When you want to store result in DataTable you would instantiate it with DataColumns before loop and for every reader.Read() iteration you have to invoke DataTable.NewRow(). Alternatively you can use SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: yes i prefer using SqlDataAdapter, then after getting the result from first Stored-procedure  what will doing with the second Stored-procedure how will be write it because it depend on the first stored

Comment: is the `leadticket.CreationDateLG` a parameter? If so you can modify the first view and only keep the `isfullleadticket = 1 and isold = 0` filter and in the second view you would add `VwInprogressSub1.CreationDateLG`

Comment: I am trying to do what you said but `leadticket.CreationDateLG` it is not a parameter it is a filter only when i removed it from the filter and add it as parameter gives me error because i have `group by CurrentAgentFK` i should dd it as aggregate function